# Can we disable logging functionality in testsuite's PHPUnit's configuration?

Tags: logging, phpunit

I need to run GrumPHP on pre-commit with PHPUnit task but I don't want code-coverage functionality.

Actually, we have one configuration file for PHPUnit used to launch testsuite on local or on jenkins.

We define logging section in this file, but this is for all declared testsuites.

Is it possible to disable code coverage functionality for one particular testsuite ? Or I need to define one another configuration file for GrumPHP?

Comment: It's easy enough to make and use a different config file.

Comment: Yes I know but I wonder if it's possible to do in one file to avoid doucle maintenance :p

Comment: Not without taking the logging config out, and setting it instead on the commands parameters.